# preg_replace string with tags

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string where I want to remove everything between the following tags including those tags:

```
<br> and the </span>

<a class='interactive' href='http://mathbench.umd.edu/modules/microbio_counting-methods/page01.htm' target='_blank' alt='Counting bacteria' >Counting bacteria<br><span class='attribute'> - University of Maryland</span></a>
```

I have tried `preg_replace('/<br>.*?</a>/', '', $link)` but that seems to remove the href...

Any ideas how I should do this?

**EDIT:**
After using:

```
 preg_replace('/<br>.*?<\/span>/', '', $link)
```

I now see in the source:

```
 <tr>
    <td><a class='interactive' href='http://www.proteinatlas.org/' target='_blank' alt='The protein atlas' >The protein atlas<br><span class='attribute'> - Uppsala Univeristät</td> 
    <td width='16' align='center' valign='middle'><a class='delete_link' href='#' data_link='%3Ca+class%3D%27interactive%27+href%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.proteinatlas.org%2F%27+target%3D%27_blank%27+alt%3D%27The+protein+atlas%27+%3EThe+protein+atlas%3Cbr%3E%3Cspan+class%3D%27attribute%27%3E+-+Uppsala+Univerist%C3%A4t' data_topic='161' data_introduction=''><img src="../images/delete.png" width="16" height="16" alt="delete" title="delete this link" border='0' /></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> funded by the Knut and Alice Wallenberg Foundation</span></a></td> 
    <td width='16' align='center' valign='middle'><a class='delete_link' href='#' data_link='+funded+by+the+Knut+and+Alice+Wallenberg+Foundation%3C%2Fspan%3E%3C%2Fa%3E' data_topic='161' data_introduction=''><img src="../images/delete.png" width="16" height="16" alt="delete" title="delete this link" border='0' /></a></td>
  </tr>
```

**Edit:**  Also tried;

```
preg_replace('/<br><span class=\'attribute\'>.*?<\/span>/', '', $link)
```

but problem persists.

**EDIT**

Still see the source showing as:

```
<a class='interactive' href='http://www.tinyurl.com/immunologygame/' target='_blank' alt='Innate Immunology game' >Innate Immunology game<br><span class='attribute'> - University of Ballarat</span></a>
```

Comment: If there are some newlines in the subject string then try to add "s" modifier to the regex: `/<br>.*?<\/span>/s`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this short pattern:

```
/<br>.*?<\/span>/
```

The output will be something like this:

```
<a class='interactive' href='http://mathbench.umd.edu/modules/microbio_counting-methods/page01.htm' target='_blank' alt='Counting bacteria' >Counting bacteriabla</a>
```

Comment: I would have thought that would work, but the span tag is still showing: I have edited OP with source that shows.

Comment: Actually I can see it working, but a problem arises when there is a comma in the content between the span tags...how do I escape that?

Comment: Mmm, evenafter manually removing any commas in text between the span tags I still see the br and span tags in the source...see edit in OP

Comment: The problem was having commas in the span text.  I have set to strip commas and replace with dash, so this fixes the problem after tuxtimo's solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```
<?php

$str = "<a class='interactive' href='http://mathbench.umd.edu/modules/microbio_counting-methods/page01.htm' target='_blank' alt='Counting bacteria' >Counting bacteria<br><span class='attribute'> - University of Maryland</span></a>";

$r = '/<br>(.+?)<\/span>/';

$str = preg_replace($r, '', $str);

echo $str;

?>
```

**Output :**

```
<a class='interactive' href='http://mathbench.umd.edu/modules/microbio_counting-methods/page01.htm' target='_blank' alt='Counting bacteria' >Counting bacteria</a>
```

---

**Demo :** http://regexr.com?33s84

Comment: I think the group in your pattern is in his case not necessary.

Comment: @tuxtimo Well, actually it's not. I just use to have groups (either like this one, or non-capturing ones (which would be better to be honest)), in order to make a regex more visually "revealing" and explanatory (well, in a way...).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$str = "<a class='interactive' href='http://mathbench.umd.edu/modules/microbio_counting-methods/page01.htm' target='_blank' alt='Counting bacteria' >Counting bacteria<br><span class='attribute'> - University of Maryland</span></a>";

echo htmlspecialchars(preg_replace('#(<a[^>]+?>)([^<>]+).*#i', '$1$2</a>', $str));
```